# ngxs: How to test dynamic selectors

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selector, ngxs

I followed the official documentation on testing ngxs selectors (https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/recipes/unit-testing#testing-selectors), however it doesn't cover how to unittest dynamic selectors created with `createSelector`.

My normal selector just gets the state as an argument so I can easly test it by passing a prepared state and comparing the output.

```
@Selector()
static nachweise(state: NachweisStateModel) {
  return state.nachweise;
}



//Setup state   
const state = {...};

//Compare expectations
expect(NachweisState.nachweise(state)).toEqual(...);
```

My dynamic selector looks like this:

```
@Selector()
static nachweisById(id: string) {
  return createSelector([NachweisState], state => {
    return state.nachweise.find(nachweis => nachweis.id === id);
  });
}
```

The only parameter it gets is the id by which it selects, but not the state. The State is automagically passed in by specifying it as the first parameter to `createSelector` and I don't know how I should test this selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [the documentation has been updated](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/recipes/unit-testing):

```
it('should select requested animal names from state', () => {
  const zooState = {
    animals: [
      { type: 'zebra', name: 'Andy'},
      { type: 'panda', name: 'Betty'},
      { type: 'zebra', name: 'Crystal'},
      { type: 'panda', name: 'Donny'},
    ]
  };
  const value = ZooSelectors.animalNames('zebra')(zooState);
  expect(value).toEqual(['Andy', 'Crystal']);
});
```